# How to select an alt based on what the src of the image is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my situation:

I want to influence an action based upon one img's alt, but I have two img's that both have as their `alt='Grow Your Business'`.  I can't alter either of the alt's, the business is in control of this thru a CMS.  Since their is no other way for me to uniquely identify the element that I want to influence other than the verbiage in the alt, what I am trying to accomplish is to select by the alt, and then write a javascript function that if this particular img's alt has as a src that contains 'GrowYourBusiness_on.gif', execute this action.

Below is what I have, but my syntax isn't currently workable.  What am I doing wrong?  I am not sure if I can use "this" in the way that I am trying to right now.

```
$("[alt='Grow Your Business']").hover(function () {
  if ($("this:contains('GrowYourBusiness_on.gif')"))
     $("#MainNavItems_7").show("fast").css({ "z-index": "3000" });    
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[alt='Grow Your Business']").hover(function () {

    if ($(this).attr('src')=="GrowYourBusiness_on.gif")

        $("#MainNavItems_7").show("fast").css({ "z-index": "3000" });    

});
```

But why not just...

```
$("[src='GrowYourBusiness_on.gif'][alt='Grow Your Business']")
```

Test for both in the initial seletor.

Comment: In case the image `src` has a path (`foobar/GrowYourBusiness_on.gif`), you could also use the "attribute ends with" selector, `$=`: `[src$='GrowYourBusiness_on.gif']`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the attribute `src`:

```
$("[alt='Grow Your Business']").hover(function () {
     if ($(this).attr('src') == 'GrowYourBusiness_on.gif'){
         $("#MainNavItems_7").show("fast").css({ "z-index": "3000" });    
     }
});
```

If the path is absolute, then you could look into the string for the substring you are looking for:

```
if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf('GrowYourBusiness_on.gif') != -1){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ($(this).is('[src$="GrowYourBusiness_on.gif"]')) {
```

You may also want to use `mouseenter` instead of `hover`, since the `hover` callback will run on both mouseenter and mouseleave.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gERVF/

Answer (score 0):

Attach your hover only to images that contain the gif in the src attribute, and have the alt text.

```
$('img[src="GrowYourBusiness_on.gif"][alt="Grow Your Business"]').hover(function(){
    $("#MainNavItems_7").show("fast").css({ "z-index": "3000" });
});
```

jQuery's selector for `[attribute="xxx"]` already [performs a contains for the text](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/).

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.